# Set default user variable in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash shell script, run where the user is expected to pass a path into it as the $1 variable. How can I determine if $1 is missing and define a default value instead for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the length of the variable.

```
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo '$1 is zero-length. Please provide a value!'
fi
```

If you just want to use a default value, you can use a brace expansion.

```
first_param=${1:-defaultvalue}
```

The `${varname:-foo}` construct will use the value of `varname` if it is set, or use what follows the `:-` if it is not set.

Comment: Useful to know: `${parameter-default}` and `${parameter:-default}` are almost equivalent. The extra `:` makes a difference only when `parameter` has been declared, but is null. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean detect if a value is missing, or if the directories in the path are missing?
For the former:

```
MYPATH=$1
if [[ -z $MYPATH ]]
then
    MYPATH=$MYDEFAULTPATH
fi
```

for the latter:

```
MYPATH=$1
if [[ ! -d $MYPATH ]]
then
    MYPATH=$MYDEFAULTPATH
fi
```

Comment: Since he mentions bash specifically, you should be using `[[` over `[`

Comment: Why is `[[` more appropriate than `[` ?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: You can find that on the bash wiki at [FAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)